# How to properly propagate multiplex signal names to scope legend via bus system? (Simulink)

Tags: matlab, legend, simulink

*I substituted my originial question, the problem is still the same, but the conditions are now different. To review the original question, have a look at the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20424697/revisions).*

I'm looking for a way to interactively select the signals I want to get displayed in my scope Block. The `Bus Selector` Block with the property `Output as Bus` does exactly that. I can select all desired signals conveniently without changing any block or signal dimensions.

[image]
[image]

But the `scope` block can obviously not handle properly signal names of buses. Therefore my scope legends are wrong:

[image]

If I don't set the `Output as Bus` property and `Mux` the signal together into the scope block it displays the right signal names. But this is no option as I'd need to adjust the `Mux`-dimension according to the signals selected.

Are there any workarounds?

*(A `Floating Scope` is no option either)*

Comment: How does the output of the subsystem look? The legend is similar to plotting an array with 4 elements. Make sure there is no implicit bus to vector conversion. Did you set the out port from the subsystem to match the bus data type?

Comment: Check this: double-click on out port, switch to Signal Attributes, set Data type to your bus definition. The icon of the out port should also change.

Comment: @remus: all my signals are simple doubles. Therefore I set the output also to double (see screenshot). No change. I also tried to set the `Port dimensions` to `4`, no change.

Comment: But the data type should be changed to bus (not double) in order to propagate as bus signals. Otherwise Simulink implicitly converts your bus to a vector and signal names are lost outside the subsystem.

Comment: @remus: I actually tried this as well, resulting in the error shown above. I create a little minimal example and upload it, so you could set it up properly, would that be possible?

Comment: You're right. It doesn't work. I just made a MnWE. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @remus I added a link to a minimal example I prepared. Thanks for your help already!

Comment: It looks like Simulink doesn't know how to propagate bus signal names from subsytems. I made a dummy workaround: a series of bus selector and bus creator. https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwgql0dd0nigp93/minimalexampleBuses2.slx

Comment: @remus it's the same I implemented by myself in the meanwhile. Ugly, but necessary. Thank you anyway! Argh, well actually I did all this to get the possibility of variable bus dimensions dependent on my masked subsystem, I will get in trouble again with that solution. I'm going to fiddle around some more time,

Comment: File a feature request to mathworks. Such a feature should exist in Simulink.

Comment: @remus: I completely modified the question. But it probably won't increase the probabilty for a solution, will it?

Comment: @am304: you always have a solution for simulink questions and you're a bus expert :) Any ideas?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Sorry, I'm stumped... You can always file a bug report with MathWorks but that won't solve your immediate problem. I could imagine a subsystem with some callbacks that would change the wiring and number of inputs to the Mux block based on user input, but just thinking about it, it's going to be very ugly to implement.

Comment: When you **consider name on each signal** (_by twice clicks on signals line_) and then can see _those names_ on the scope! ;)